# Is there an ASP.NET CMS that doesn't complicate the integration of Web Forms components?

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system

Let me explain first that I'm new to web development and it's not my area of interest. A few months ago I made a quick research of various web technologies and I decided that I will learn ASP.NET - Web Forms. This has been working out for me for a simple site - I like the master pages idea and the modularity idea supported by custom controls. I made a few custom controls that I surely wouldn't find on the internet.

Problems began when I started to look for a blog that I could elegantly integrate into my existing master page with my existing themes and styles. The best thing I could find was BlogEngine.NET. But it is designed as a standalone blogging system, not as a control (I just want to display the posts and comments). Isolating what I want from the code base and integrating it with my web app is going to take unknown amount of work and time.

So I turned towards CMS with a blog - Orchard looked very promising. Then I realised that integrating my own Web Forms into Orchard is almost an impossible task for me (definitely not something I have time for). What do I think is the problem here? The CMS is not providing reusable components for easy integration in the spirit of Web Forms - it locks me in - as long as I stick to what they offer I am safe, but once I want to integrate my own Web Form - it's a no go.

So, do you know any NET CMS that allows integration of third party web controls just like you would do without CMS? Or better still - is just a collection of isolated, reusable components?

Comment: DotNetNuke comes to mind... But that may be a bit too far off the reservation for your taste.

Comment: Have you looked at Kentico? It is paid, but allows full customization/integration.

Comment: DotNetNuke or Umbraco are two you might want to take a look at

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old thread, but don't know if you ever got the info you needed. If you are OK with commercial software, you might consider **[SiteFinity](http://www.sitefinity.com/)** (by Telerik) as it uses master pages to generate layout, and webforms user controls for custom code.  If you are more in need of an open source/free product, you might consider looking at **[MojoPortal](http://www.mojoportal.com/)** or **[CarrotCake CMS](https://github.com/ninianne98/CarrotCakeCMS)**.